# Turn camelCaseWords from data attribute into "Camel Case Words" 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of links with custom HTML5 data attributes like this one: `data-test="justExample"`

```
<a href="#" data-test="somethingSpecial">
    This should output "Something Special"
</a>
```

I want to return this value as `"Just Example"` instead of "`justExample"`.

Feel free to edit [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28NpS/) I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var str = $(this).data('test'); // get the concated string
    var arr = str.split(""); // Convert the string to array
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  // iterate over the characters 
        if (arr[i].match(/[A-Z]/))  // if the char is uppercase
            arr.splice(i, 0, " "); // add a space before it
    }

    arr[0] = arr[0].toUpperCase();    // upper the first char.
    var splitedString = arr.join(""); // convert the array to string
    alert(splitedString); // alert the string.
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTMKn/1)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var input = $(this).data('test'),
      output = input.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1).replace(/[A-Z][a-z]/, ' $&');
  alert(output);
});​
```

It might be better to write a general function to convert camel-casing into a neat string, but there's a demo of the example above working here: http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/mFbHK/

Comment: Note that you can use `$&` in a regex replacement for the entire matched pattern, so you can get rid of your unnecessary grouping. Also (although it was ill-specified in the original) this answer will turn "rocketsByACME" into "Rockets By A C M E".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short, simple version:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var t = $(this).data('test');
  alert(t.replace( /^[a-z]|[a-z][A-Z]/g, function(s){
    return s.length==1 ? s.toUpperCase() : s.replace(/^./,'$& ');
  });
});
```

Alternatively, wrapped up into a more re-usable function that also self-documents your intent:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alert(deCamel($(this).data('test')));
});

function deCamel(str){
  return str.replace( /^[a-z]|[a-z][A-Z]/g, function(s){
    return s.length==1 ? s.toUpperCase() : s.replace(/^./,'$& ');
  });
}
```